I need to install an application but I'm offline
Is there a way i can download something like an exe file and install in the computer that has no internet connection?

Ubuntu or for that matter any Linux does not run EXE files that is a Microsoft thing.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; as the type of package will determine how you download (eg. snap packages come from different source to deb packages), but you can download the file; copy to media, walk it to the machine & install (done long ago with magnetic tapes, then [floppy] disk, now thumb-drives).  Yes mobile phones can also be used to provide alternate internet connections too.
